# Otsu method in image thresholding with no bi-modal histograms?

Tags: image-processing

I read about Otsu's method which performs automatically image thresholding.  The algorithm assumes that the image to be thresholded contains two classes of pixels(bi-modal histogram).
This is absolute or we can adapt the algorithm and we can do for example thresholding to an image with three classes of pixels or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fewer numbers say 3-4 classes of pixels, you could apply it repetitively if the distributions are spread well apart.

Comment: Think about it. Coursera expects you to do your own assignment.